# Python- Launch executable, browse to directory, and click 'okay'

Tags: python

I'm trying to automate form submission with a Blaise executable called Manipula.
I can successfully open the exe like this:

`subprocess.Popen("Manipula.exe")`

This brings up a dialog box like this:
[image]

I then want to automatically fill the text box with a directory like C:\test.msu, and automate 'OK', is there anyway to do this in Python?

Comment: You would want something like [pywinauto](https://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/) if you are on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for all of this.  Just run a command prompt with the second specification as the file you want to browse to.